# I want to use READ_NOS to read a file from S3 and get all rows to return. But it only returns some rows

Tags: teradata

I  want to use READ_NOS to  read a file  from S3  and get all rows to return.  But  it  only returns  some  rows .

I create a  foreign table for  a parquet file.

but result:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9jmA.jpg

use studio still the same result:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5EBO.jpg

how to get the all rows  return ?

Comment: So it appears one file doesn't match the FOREIGN TABLE structurally, and for most rows there are column values that fail conversion to the data types stated in the FOREIGN TABLE definition.

Comment: yes   data content has some problem.   I  fixed  the content finally get all rows return.

Comment: And  this takes me a lot of time to debug.  Thanks  Fred.  :)

Answer (score 1):

the first SQL (COUNT*) show the number of records. The second one the number of Parquet Files. So in average each files holds 6.470 records.

There is a [Teradata Orange Book dedicated to Use of NOS](https://docs.teradata.com/v/u/8VDDkw6IYDwWtW5DriVnAA) with some backgroud but as well some example SQL. Chapter 5 of this is focussed on Parquet Files.
It looks like `RETURNTYPE ('NOSREAD_PARQUET_SCHEMA')` is important in the combination os READ_NOS and Parquet.

Comment: yes,  But the return  message  got me confused. It doesn't  let me think about the  data content problem.